# Shopware 6: How to place the filter on top instead of the sidebar?

Tags: twig, shopware, shopware6

How to place the filter to be adjacent to the sorting in the storefront?
From the layout editor, I moved the `sidebar-filter` on top of the listing, but it is not aligned with the sorting as I want to make a expand/collapse functionality.

How can I place the filter on the same level as the sorting?

*This is my code so far:*

**src/custom/plugins/myTheme/src/Resources/views/storefront/component/product/listing.html.twig:**

```
{% block element_product_listing_pagination_nav_actions %}
    <div class="cms-element-product-listing-actions row mb-4">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-start">
            {% block element_product_listing_filter %}
                {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/block/cms-block-sidebar-filter.html.twig' %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
            {% block element_product_listing_sorting %}
                {{ parent() }}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**src/custom/plugins/IabTheme/src/Resources/views/storefront/block/cms-block-sidebar-filter.html.twig:**

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/block/cms-block-sidebar-filter.html.twig' %}

{% block block_sidebar_filter %}
    {% set element = block.slots.getSlot('content') %}
    {% set columns = 1 %}

    <div class="col-12 iab-block-sidebar-filter" data-cms-element-id="{{ element.id }}">
        <div class="font-weight-bold pb-475">
            <div class="iab-filter-wrapper">{{ 'general.filterSidebarHeadline'|trans|sw_sanitize|upper }}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="filter-inputs collapse">
            {% block block_sidebar_filter_inner %}
                {{ parent() }}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <script id="toggle-filters" type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var clickableDiv = document.querySelector('.iab-filter-wrapper');
            var contentDiv = document.querySelector('.filter-inputs');

            clickableDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
                contentDiv.classList.toggle('collapse');
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**Screenshots:**

*Shopping experience layout editor:*
[image: Shopping experience layout editor]
*Storefront shop with filter on top:*
[image: Storefront shop with filter on top]

Comment: "*triggering a 500 error the sw_include filter part*" - Please add the full error to your question

Comment: There is no error message I can see, it is a browser error .. nothing in the logs, nor the debugger tool.

Comment: If you have any other approach to just place the filter with the same level as the sorting, please let me know .. as this is the major issue, not the server error :)

Comment: Are you in prod mode or dev mode? Do you really not get an error in dev mode (`APP_ENV=dev`)? I would focus on retrieving a proper error message.

Comment: The issue, is it gets an infinite loop inheriting the `@Storefront/storefront/block/cms-block-sidebar-filter.html.twig` view. I added instead the view `@Storefront/storefront/element/cms-element-sidebar-filter.html.twig` and it showed the filters fine, but when playing with the filters, it disappears (because shopware sends a requests and receives a rendered html for the listing component + the sort that doesn't have the filters).